# The footer which is absolute with bottom = 0 , doesn't stay at bottom

Tags: html, css

This is what I've tried so far:

```css
    .content{
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    .bottom{
     position:absolute;
     height:50px;
     line-height: 50px;
     bottom:0;
     width:80%;
     background:green;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="content">
        ......
    </div>
    <footer class="bottom">
        <p>
        this is always at bottom
        </p>
    </footer>
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5M7cL/5/) is an example too.

Did someone know why this happen, and how I can solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1.You have make small change in CSS.According to your [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/5M7cL/5/).

```
.parent {
    height:1500px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
}
.topDiv {
    display:block;
    background:silver;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
}

.bottomDiv {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

body {
    height:1500px;
    background: linear-gradient(#111, #777);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use position:fixed, to achieve this !!

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.content{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.bottom{
 position:fixed;
 height:50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 bottom:0;
 width:80%;
 background:green;
}


</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>    ......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>......<br>
</div>
<footer class="bottom">
    <p>
    this is always at bottom
    </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you! but I know 'fixed' is working, I want to know why 'absolute' does not work!